# Why do I need a 00 time zone offset to display values correctly in d3v4?

Tags: d3.js, timezone, timezone-offset

I'm trying to parse the following dates with d3:

```
20-06-18 01-02-35
20-06-18 09-13-01
```

using:

```
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%m-%y %H-%M-%S");
```

However, the console.log shows me these parsed values:

```
Date 2018-06-19T23:02:35.000Z
Date 2018-06-20T07:13:01.000Z
```

which are **off by two hours**.

---

Okay, I thought, after all, I'm sitting in the CEDT, I should probably add an offset. So I added `-02` to the dates to parse and `%Z` to the `timeParse` argument, but it's still not what I want:

```
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%m-%y %H-%M-%S %Z");
parseTime("20-06-18 01-02-35 -02") // Date 2018-06-20T03:02:35.000Z
parseTime("20-06-18 09-13-01 -02") // Date 2018-06-20T11:13:01.000Z
```

---

Long story short, asking for a `-00` offset gives me the correct values. But it seems a bit redundant to me. Why does this happen?

EDIT: Only happens in Firefox, Chrome gives me

```
Wed Jun 20 2018 09:13:01 GMT+0200
```

Still no idea why, tho.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for [`d3.utcParse`](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#locale_utcParse) instead of `d3.parseTime` in order to avoid using the local time zone:

```js
var parser = d3.utcParse("%d-%m-%y %H-%M-%S");
console.log(parser("20-06-18 01-02-35"));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

And to go back to string, you can use `d3.utcFormat` instead of `d3.timeFormat`.